# Incorrect citation call-out format

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am not sure why I do not see the expected format of referencing. I would like to see this kind of ref on a paragraph (vassiliadis et al., 2009) instead of [1]. For example, data fetched from open sources lacks quality [1] but I would like to see like this:

> data fetched from open sources lacks quality (vassiliadis et al., 2009).

I am using `\citep{vassiliadis2009survey}` to make this happen but no luck so far.

I added the package `\usepackage[round, authoryear]{natbib}`.
Now the problem is when I use that `natbib` with the provided package it throws me an error:

> ```
> ! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.(natbib)
> Press <return> to continue in numerical citation style. See the natbib package
> documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help....
>     ...mand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers
> ```

This is what I used for the template:

```
\documentclass[cameraready]{cseminar}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\lhead{CSE-E500 Seminar on Software Systems, Technologies and Security}
\rhead{Spring 2016}
\begin{document}
%==================================
\begin{abstract}
\vspace{3mm}
\noindent \textbf{KEYWORDS}: 

\end{abstract}
 %============================
\subsection{Related Study}

 \begin{figure}[h]
 \begin{center}
 \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{figures/SCS}
 \caption{Source Conceptual Schema}
 \citep{lujan2004data}
\label{fig:SCS}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
% List of references is created with bibtex.
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{technical-report}
\end{document}
```

The references file looks like this and I have 12 of those in **technical-report.bib** file:

```
 % 2009 ref year 
 @article{vassiliadis2009survey,
 title={A survey of Extract--transform--Load technology},
 author={Vassiliadis, Panos},
 journal={International Journal of Data Warehousing and Mining (IJDWM)},
 volume={5},
 number={3},
 pages={1--27},
 year={2009},
 publisher={IGI Global}
 }
```

But author year is mentioned already. Could you please help me out to fix this problem? Thanks in advance. In my paper, I am using two columns for each page.

Comment: you don't need `[breaklinks]` option for `hyperref`. that is set automatically. also `breakurls` is superfluous.  `hyperref` does break URLs correctly.

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you use.

Comment: @Mico  \bibliographystyle{plain}

Comment: Incidentally, the issue you describe is not related to either the `hyperref` or the `breakurl` package.

Comment: Where might one find a copy of the file `cseminar.cls`?

Comment: Actually there is only one I have named `cseminar.cls`  and it is in the same directory

Comment: @bhordupur - I know *you* have a copy of `cseminar.cls`. I don't, though. Is is available somewhere on the web?

Comment: No, I do not think bcoz it is hand coded.If you want to see it I can share you a link .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The bibliography style `plain` can only generate numeric-style citation call-outs.

Since you're using the `natbib` citation management package, you should (a) use the `plainnat` bibliography style, which can produce both numeric-style and authoryear-style citation call-outs, and (b) provide the option `authoryear` when loading the `natbib` package:

```
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

After making these changes, be sure to re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate the effects of these changes.

---

*Addendum*: Here's an MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@article{vassiliadis2009survey,
 title={A survey of {Extract}--transform--{Load} technology},
 author={Vassiliadis, Panos},
 journal={International Journal of Data Warehousing and Mining (IJDWM)},
 volume={5},
 number={3},
 pages={1--27},
 year={2009},
 publisher={IGI Global}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\citep{vassiliadis2009survey}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

Comment: same error still.yes I did re-run using F6,F11 but no luck.

Comment: @bhordupur - You don't have more than one `\bibliographystyle` instruction, do you? And you don't load additional citation management packages (such as `cite`) either, right? Try deleting the aux and bbl files and then re-running LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX *twice more*. If that still doesn't work, please post a complete code sample that generates the error.

Comment: I have exactly 12 different ref. in the paper. and only one bibliographystyle the one you suggested. I am gonna try it now again after deleting those files.thanks

Comment: this is error I get `! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.(natbib) Press <return> to continue in numerical citation style.See the natbib package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ...mand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers`

Comment: @bhordupur I think it's best, you add a MWE to your question, so we can see what  might cause the problem.

Comment: @bhordupur - I've augmented my answer with an MWE (minimum working example) that shows what the combination of the `plainnat` bibliography style and the `natbib` citation management package produce in terms of citation call-outs. As you can verify, the result is an authoryear-style citation call-out. If that's not the result you're getting, there must be some code in your tex file that's interfering with this outcome. Please post an MWE of your own that generates the problem behavior you wish to fix.

Comment: I have given almost everything from that file.It is bit stange that it does not work.this is what I followed before https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex

Comment: Just to let you know it works perfectly once I use cite but citep do not work even though I added the package and style.I am bit confused what shall I put as MWE.I added all in the question already